# VUE-JSON-EXCEL Change format date

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I just want to ask on how to change format date for the VUE-JSON-EXCEL library?

After i click the generate excel button, it will display in the excel a date format like this "2022-06-10T18:18:34.000Z" instead of "10/6/2022 18:18:34"

Already use moment.js but it's not working

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyVv1.png)

```
json_fields: {
    Date: 'dateReserve',
  },



<div class="col-3">
            <JsonExcel
              class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill font-weight-bold"
              :data="tempahanList"
              :fields="json_fields"
              type="csv"
              name="List Tempahan.xls"
            >
              Download Excel
            </JsonExcel>
          </div>
```

Comment: you can display dates any way you like - hard to tell you what you're doing wrong since you've shown no code though - if you're generating an excel, then it's likely you're shoving a string into a cell instead of an actual date

Comment: Sorry i have already edit the post, currently i'm using vue.js @Bravo

Comment: I know you're using vuejs - because I can **read** - wow - the code you've shown shows nothing about how you're putting dates into an excel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try for loop the result, then convert it using momentJS. I'm sure you can mate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
    json_fields: {
        "Date": {
            field: "dateReserve",
            callback: (value) => {
                return moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            },
        },
    },
},
```